# Error in CorePlot 1.5.1

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-plot, quartz-graphics

I've been getting reports from my app's users of an error inside CorePlot framework. It does not always happens and I cannot detect a pattern on how to make it crash myself. I would like to know if there is something I can do to avoid this crash.

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_MAPERR at 0x4c69ef75bec0
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: retain

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00007fff885c80dd objc_msgSend + 29
1   AppKit                               0x00007fff8f045916 +[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:] + 76
2   CorePlot                             0x0000000104f10119 CPTPopCGContext + 40
3   CorePlot                             0x0000000104f10051 -[NSAttributedString(CPTPlatformSpecificAttributedStringExtensions) drawInRect:inContext:] + 80
4   CorePlot                             0x0000000104f05822 -[CPTTextLayer renderAsVectorInContext:] + 513
5   CorePlot                             0x0000000104f06058 -[CPTLayer drawInContext:] + 55
6   QuartzCore                           0x00007fff82dfe0c3 _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 657
7   QuartzCore                           0x00007fff82dfc7fd _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 603
8   QuartzCore                           0x00007fff82dfbe81 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 35
9   QuartzCore                           0x00007fff82dfb612 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
10  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff82dfb3ae _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
11  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff82e09f19 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 71
12  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff8b53f127 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
13  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff8b53f080 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
14  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff8b530bf8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328
15  HIToolbox                            0x00007fff9130f56f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
16  HIToolbox                            0x00007fff9130f2ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
17  HIToolbox                            0x00007fff9130f12b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
18  AppKit                               0x00007fff8f0719bb _DPSNextEvent + 978
19  AppKit                               0x00007fff8f070f68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
20  AppKit                               0x00007fff8f066bf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
21  AppKit                               0x00007fff8efe3354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
22  MyApp                                0x0000000104afcc3a main (ReceiptCheck.h:4779)
23  libdyld.dylib                        0x00007fff830fd5c9 start + 1
```

I use CorePlot for 2 types of graphics: a pie and bar chart, I display 2 simultaneously, take a look:

[image]

> My app uses ARC and runs only in yosemite. Here is my code:

```
-(void)createGraphs{
    [self updateChartTextStyles];
    
    self.completedGraph = [self createGraphWithHostView:self.completedGraphHostingView];
    self.uncompletedGraph = [self createGraphWithHostView:self.uncompletedGraphHostingView];
}

-(CPTXYGraph *)createGraphWithHostView:(CPTGraphHostingView *)hostView{
    CPTXYGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc]initWithFrame:self.completedGraphHostingView.bounds];
    graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    graph.paddingBottom = 0;
    graph.paddingTop = 0;
    graph.paddingLeft = 0;
    graph.paddingRight = 0;
    graph.masksToBorder = NO;
    [graph setTitleTextStyle:self.chartTitleStyle];
    hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    return graph;
}

-(void)updateChartTextStyles{
    CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.fontName = [[ThemeManager mainFont] labelFont].fontName;
    textStyle.fontSize = [[[ThemeManager mainFont] labelFont] pointSize];
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[NSColor blackColor].CGColor];

    self.chartLabelStyle = textStyle;
    
    textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.fontName = [[ThemeManager mainFont].titleFont fontName];
    textStyle.fontSize = [[ThemeManager mainFont].titleFont pointSize];
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[NSColor blackColor].CGColor];
    
    self.chartTitleStyle = textStyle;
}

-(void)removeAllPlotsInGraph:(CPTGraph *)graph{
    NSArray *allPlots = [graph.allPlots copy];
    for (CPTPlot *plot in allPlots) {
        [graph removePlot:plot];
    }
}

-(void)setPieChartPlotToGraph:(CPTGraph *)graph withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier{
    [self removeAllPlotsInGraph:graph];
    CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc]init];
    pieChart.dataSource = self;
    pieChart.delegate = self;
    pieChart.pieRadius =  (graph.hostingView.bounds.size.height*.7)/2;
    pieChart.identifier = identifier;
    CPTMutableShadow *shadow = [CPTMutableShadow shadow];
    shadow.shadowColor = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[NSColor grayColor].CGColor];
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 3;
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, -1);
    [pieChart setShadow:shadow];
    
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop          = 0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight        = 0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom       = 0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft         = 0;
    
    [graph.axisSet setHidden:YES];
    
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace       = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.yRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)
                                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromInt(10)];
    plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)
                                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromInt(10)];
    
    [graph addPlot:pieChart];
}

-(CPTBarPlot *)createBarPlotWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withColor1:(NSColor *)color1 andColor2:(NSColor *)color2{
    CPTBarPlot *barChart = [[CPTBarPlot alloc]init];
    barChart.paddingBottom = 0;
    barChart.paddingLeft = 0;
    barChart.paddingRight = 0;
    barChart.paddingTop = 0;
    barChart.dataSource = self;
    barChart.delegate = self;
    barChart.identifier = identifier;
    barChart.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromFloat(.7);
    barChart.barCornerRadius = 6;
    barChart.lineStyle = nil;

    CPTMutableShadow *shadow = [CPTMutableShadow shadow];
    shadow.shadowColor = [CPTColor grayColor];
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 3;
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, -1);
    [barChart setShadow:shadow];
    
    CPTGradient *gradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:color1.CGColor] endingColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:color2.CGColor]];
    barChart.fill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:gradient];
    return barChart;
}

-(void)setBarPlotToGraph:(CPTGraph *)graph withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier andComposedColor:(ComposedColor *)composedColor{

    [self removeAllPlotsInGraph:graph];
    
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop          = 10.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight        = 0.00;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom       = 30.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft         = 0;
    

    [graph addPlot:[self createBarPlotWithIdentifier:identifier withColor1:composedColor.baseColor andColor2:composedColor.brightColor]];
    
    
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace       = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.yRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)
                                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromInt(15)];
    plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1)
                                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromInt(8)];
    
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *xAxis = axisSet.xAxis;
    xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
    xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
    xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0];

    
    
    NSArray *dayOfWeekLabels = [NSDate daysOfTheWeekNamesAbbreviated:YES];
    NSMutableArray *customXLabels = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSDate *tempDate = self.startDate;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc]initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i",dayOfWeekLabels[i], tempDate.day] textStyle:self.chartLabelStyle];
        tempDate = [tempDate addDays:1];
        label.tickLocation = [@(i) decimalValue];
        label.offset = xAxis.labelOffset + xAxis.majorTickLength;
//        label.rotation = M_PI/4.0;
        [customXLabels addObject:label];
    }
    
    xAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customXLabels];
    
    CPTXYAxis *yAxis = axisSet.yAxis;
    yAxis.title = @"Value";
    yAxis.titleOffset = 50.f;
    yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0];

    
}

-(void)updateCharts{
    [self updateCompletedChart];
    [self updateUncompletedChart];
}

-(void)updateUncompletedChart{

    self.uncompletedTasksGraphData = [self calculateChartDataWithTasks:self.uncompletedTasks groupType:[self groupTypeForGraph] chartType:[self chartTypeForGraph]];
    
    if (self.pieChartButton.state) {
        [self setPieChartPlotToGraph:self.uncompletedGraph withIdentifier:UNCOMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER];
    }
    else if(self.barChartButton.state){
        [self setBarPlotToGraph:self.uncompletedGraph withIdentifier:UNCOMPLETED_BAR_CHART_IDENTIFIER andComposedColor:[[ComposedColorManager defaultInstance]composedColorWithCode:@"Red"]];
    }
    
    [self.uncompletedGraph reloadData];
}

-(void)updateCompletedChart{

    self.completedTasksGraphData = [self calculateChartDataWithTasks:self.completedTasks groupType:[self groupTypeForGraph] chartType:[self chartTypeForGraph]];
    
    if (self.pieChartButton.state) {
        [self setPieChartPlotToGraph:self.completedGraph withIdentifier:COMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER];
    }
    else if(self.barChartButton.state){
        [self setBarPlotToGraph:self.completedGraph withIdentifier:COMPLETED_BAR_CHART_IDENTIFIER andComposedColor:[[ComposedColorManager defaultInstance]composedColorWithCode:@"Green"]];
    }
    
    
    [self.completedGraph reloadData];
}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark Graph Data Source
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

-(NSMutableArray *)chartDataForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier{
    if (identifier == COMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER || identifier == COMPLETED_BAR_CHART_IDENTIFIER) {
        return self.completedTasksGraphData;
    }
    else if(identifier == UNCOMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER || identifier == UNCOMPLETED_BAR_CHART_IDENTIFIER){
        return self.uncompletedTasksGraphData;
    }
    else{
        throwNotImplementedException;
    }
}


-(NSUInteger )numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot{
    if (plot.identifier == COMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER || plot.identifier == UNCOMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER) {
        return [[self chartDataForIdentifier:(NSString *)plot.identifier] count];
    }
    else{
        return 7;
    }
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx{
    if (plot.identifier == COMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER || plot.identifier == UNCOMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER) {
        if (fieldEnum == CPTPieChartFieldSliceWidth) {
            NSMutableArray *graphData = [self chartDataForIdentifier:(NSString *)plot.identifier];
            return [graphData[idx] numberValue];
        }
        else{
            return @(0);
        }
    }
    else if(plot.identifier == COMPLETED_BAR_CHART_IDENTIFIER || plot.identifier == UNCOMPLETED_BAR_CHART_IDENTIFIER){
        if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) {
            return @(idx);
        }
        else if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY){
            NSDate *date = [self.startDate addDays:idx];
            NSMutableArray *graphData = [self chartDataForIdentifier:(NSString *)plot.identifier];
            float sum = [graphData chartDataSumWithDate:date];
            return @(sum);
        }
        else{
            return @(0);
        }
    }
    else{
        throwNotImplementedException;
    }
}

-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx{

    
    if (plot.identifier == COMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER || plot.identifier == UNCOMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER) {
        NSMutableArray *chartDataArray = [self chartDataForIdentifier:(NSString *)plot.identifier];

        ChartData *chartData =  chartDataArray[idx];
        CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc]initWithText:[chartData labelWithPercentage]];
        [textLayer setTextStyle:self.chartLabelStyle];
        return textLayer;
    }
    else{
        NSMutableArray *chartData = [self chartDataForIdentifier:(NSString *)plot.identifier];
        NSDate *date = [[self.startDate addDays:idx] dateAsDateWithoutTime];
        float sum = [chartData chartDataSumWithDate:date];
        if (sum == 0) {
            return nil;
        }
        CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc]initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", sum]];
        return textLayer;
    }


}

-(CPTFill *)sliceFillForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    if (pieChart.identifier == COMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER || pieChart.identifier == UNCOMPLETED_PIE_CHART_IDENTIFIER) {
        NSMutableArray *chartData = [self chartDataForIdentifier:(NSString *)pieChart.identifier];
        ChartData *data = chartData[index];
        if (data.color && data.color2) {
            CPTColor *cptColor1, *cptColor2;
            cptColor1 = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:data.color.CGColor];
            cptColor2 = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:data.color2.CGColor];
            CPTGradient *gradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:cptColor1 endingColor:cptColor2];
            return [CPTFill fillWithGradient:gradient];
        }
        else{
            CPTColor *color = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:data.color.CGColor];
            CPTFill *fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:color];
            return fill;
        }
    }
    else{
        throwNotImplementedException;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue has been fixed. Release 1.6 should be out soon, or you can pull the latest code from [GitHub](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot).